# Android updating ListView dynamically for images

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, parse-server

I need to update the list with images retrieved in the background using Parse service. Using below code, I could retrieve images and display but interaction is quite slow. Is there any better way to update the ListView dynamically without impacting user interaction speed?

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> userFeedQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Offers");        
    userFeedQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                if (objects.size() > 0){
                    for (ParseObject object:objects){
                        final String offerName = object.getString("offerName");
                        final String offerDetail = object.getString("offerDetails");
                        final Bitmap[] offerImage = new Bitmap[1];
                        ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.getParseFile("offerImage");
                        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null){
                                    offerImage[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);

                                    offerModelList.add(new OfferModel(offerName,offerDetail, offerImage[0]));
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                adapter = new OffersAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.offers_table,offerModelList);
                offersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use third party to show ur images like glide,picasso etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can replace ParseImageView with Picaso or Glide, but i prefere Picaso.

Replace

```
ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.getParseFile("offerImage");
```

With this

```
String OfferImageUrl = object.getParseFile("offerImage");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(OfferImageUrl)) {
            Picasso.with(this) // use getContext or contex for fragments or adapter
                    .load(OfferImageUrl)
                    .error(android.R.drawable.error) // your own error image
                    .into(mOfferImage); // mOfferImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.offer_image); 
        }
```

Hope this help. Let me know for any assistance about this question.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's not working. I'm storing the retrieved images into array and loaded into ListView. When I use CallBack function image is not being loaded.